# "You cannot use current statement between CLASS DEFINITION ...and ENDCLASS" error

Tags: oop, abap

I am getting error that You cannot use current statement between CLASS DEFINITION .... AND ENDCLASS. Following is the sample example of ABAP class.

```
CLASS c1 DEFINITION. 
  PUBLIC SECTION.     
  STATICS static TYPE i VALUE 10. 
  METHODS add_one.

ENDCLASS. 

CLASS c1 IMPLEMENTATION. 

  METHOD add_one.
      static = static + 1. 
  ENDMETHOD.  

ENDCLASS.
```

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Comment: And it indicates the line number corresponding to `STATICS static...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`STATICS` should be declared **inside** procedures and are only accessible locally.

If you want to be able to access the value outside of the method you should declare the variable as a normal class/static attribute:

```
CLASS c1 DEFINITION. 
  PUBLIC SECTION.     
  CLASS-DATA static TYPE i VALUE 10. 
  METHODS add_one.
ENDCLASS. 

CLASS c1 IMPLEMENTATION. 
  METHOD add_one.
      static = static + 1. 
  ENDMETHOD.  
ENDCLASS.
```

Answer (score 1):

Only `DATA` and `CLASS-DATA` are allowed to declare attributes in classes and interfaces.

In a class, `STATICS` is only allowed in the implementation part of a static method (declared with `CLASS-METHODS`).